# Django Rest Framework with either a slug or a pk lookup field for the DetailAPIView

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have an api list of posts with Django Rest Framework. Knowing that **I slugify my post title**, whenever the user provides a title to her post, I want to capture the post api detail with the pk (the default lookup field in DRF) when the slug object is not provided, or using the slug field if the post has a title.

In my api folder of the post application, I wrote the following views.py:

```
class PostDetailAPIView(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
   queryset = Post.objects.all()
   serializer_class = serializers.PostDetailSerializer
   try:
      lookup_field = 'slug'
   except:
      lookup_field = 'pk'
```

And provided the corresponding urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
   url(r'^$', PostListAPIView.as_view(), name='list-api'),
   url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', PostDetailAPIView.as_view(), 
       name='detail-api'),
   url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$', PostDetailAPIView.as_view(), name='detail-
       api'),
]
```

This approach works perfectly when a post has a slugified (title) lookup. But the post detail view for a post with no slug shows the following:

```
HTTP 404 Not Found
Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

{
  "detail": "Not found."
}
```

Any suggestions on how to show the post api detail for either a pk or a slug fields lookup? Preferably with no code repitition in the urls.py.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: Your urls.py works with the **first matched** url. So it can not find your second url.

Second: In my opinion you should either stick to the "pk" Version (which is what REST states) or the slug version for the lookup. So in general i would anticipate the process of either looking for a pk or a slug.

I know this does not yet solve your answer to 100% but it should provide you a overlook on what's going on and what a REST Endpoint might look like.

Comment: Yes I was thinking maybe I should build the slug no matter what (generating a slug either the user providing a title for her post or not). I think I will redo the logic for my random slug generator function and fix the lookup field for slug once and for all. Cheers mate.

Comment: I'm glad that this helped you. How about considering a Post title as required for the user ? I'm not sure what you are building but this sounds reasonable for me.

Comment: Hey Chgad. I am buoding an instagram clone. Instagram posts have none required titles. So I tought maybe I do the same.

Comment: If my Answer helped you, and ,you consider it as a solution would you be so kind and mark it as solution?

Comment: Done. Let us keep in touch I will be having lots of questions for my project.

Comment: Yea, no problem. Contact me whenever you want.

Answer (score 0):

Using two different parameter for a single view seems to be like a bad practice to me, i will suggest you use one of them and in your view, you do a try/catch  since pk will be of integer type and title will be of string type, you can check the type of the url parameter then do your logic

Comment: Can you please elaborate more. It seems that you suggsetion corresponds to what I already did. Thank you.

Comment: You have two urls pattern, i suggest you use just one url pattern and do a try catch in the view to check the parameter of the url. since pk is of int type and slug will be string. You can use the type to determine what was passed